# create a trigger need to update table 2 on update of table1

Tags: mysql, triggers

Would like to create a trigger in mysql need to 
update t2.orderstatus as 'inactive' on update of t2.inactivedate and 
update t2.orderstatus as 'active' on update of t2.activedate. Tried to adapt below one. but failed

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_on_stockhistory_update;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_on_stockhistory_update
AFTER update ON stockhistory.inactivedate
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE  mastersku
    SET ordernow ='InActive'
    WHERE   `SSKU`  = NEW.SSKU;

END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: You need a space between delimiter and ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set trigger on field change. It may be only on table level:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_on_stockhistory_update;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `trigger_on_stockhistory_update` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `stockhistory`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.inactivedate <> NEW.inactivedate THEN
        UPDATE  mastersku
        SET ordernow ='InActive'
        WHERE   `SSKU`  = NEW.SSKU;
    END IF;

    IF OLD.activedate <> NEW.activedate THEN
        UPDATE  mastersku
        SET ordernow ='Active'
        WHERE   `SSKU`  = NEW.SSKU;
    END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Or a little elegant query using CASE statement:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_on_stockhistory_update;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `trigger_on_stockhistory_update` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `stockhistory`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE  mastersku
        SET ordernow = CASE
            WHEN OLD.inactivedate <> NEW.inactivedate THEN 'InActive'
            WHEN OLD.activedate <> NEW.activedate THEN 'Active' 
            ELSE ordernow
        END
        WHERE
          SSKU = NEW.SSKU;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this would still fail because of the same error  it has to be DELIMITER ; with a space between DELIMIER and ;

Comment: Edited. Changed `END;$$` to `END$$`